# Writing to /dev/tty

Tags: linux, unix

When I run the `tty` comand on my shell (bash), it says `/dev/pts/1`, which is a pseudo-terminal.

But when I run `echo "hello, world" > /dev/tty`, it still writes to the screen. Shouldn't I have to write to `/dev/pts/1` instead? Why does this happpen?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pty.7.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/dev/tty` is a pseudo-device that is used to reference the current *real* tty a given process is attached to.

Comment: Ok. So writing to `/dev/tty` will write to `/dev/pts/1` (in my case) ?

Comment: Yes it is the case